# застрял на такой задаче

Tags: python

Приведите переменные к нужному типу, выполните необходимые операции над ними, передайте значения в f-строку и напечатайте фразу Суммой чисел 1, 2 и 3 — будет 6.
В решении должны быть применены все три переменные; такое решение не будет принято:

```python
print('Результатом сложения чисел 1, 2 и 3 будет 6')
```

###### Код:

```python
a = 1
b = '2'
c = ['Анатолий', 3.15, '3 поросёнка']

result = f'Суммой чисел {}, {} и {} будет {}'
print(result)
```

Comment: Внимание, вопрос!

Comment: Тебе для начала сюда - [ask]

Answer (score 1):

a, b, len(c), a, int(b), len(c)

Comment: суперответ, лучше не видел!